# Reverse engineering iWork '13 formats

Tags: macos, cocoa, serialization, format, reverse-engineering

Prior versions of Apple's iWork suite used a very simple document format:

- documents were Bundles of resources (folders, zipped or not)
- the bundle contained an `index.apxl[z]` file describing the document structure in a proprietary but fairly easy to understand schema

iWork '13 has completely redone the format. Documents are still bundles, but what was in the index XML file is now encoded in a set of binary files with type suffix `.iwa` packed into `Index.zip`.

In Keynote, for example, there are the following `iwa` files:

```
AnnotationAuthorStorage.iwa
CalculationEngine.iwa
Document.iwa
DocumentStylesheet.iwa
MasterSlide-{n}.iwa
Metadata.iwa
Slide{m}.iwa
ThemeStylesheet.iwa
ViewState.iwa
Tables/DataList.iwa
```

for `MasterSlide`s 1…*n* and `Slide`s 1…*m*

The purpose of each of these is quite clear from their naming. The files even appear uncompressed, with essentially all content text directly visible as strings among the binary blobs (albeit with some like RTF/NSAttributedString/similar-related garbage in the midst of the readable ASCII characters).

I have posted the unpacked `Index` of a simple example Keynote document here: https://github.com/jrk/iwork-13-format.

However, the overall file format is non-obvious to me. Apple has a long history of using simple, platform-standard formats like plists for encoding most of their documents, but there is no clear type tag at the start of the files, and it is not obvious to me what these `iwa` files are.

Do these files ring any bells? Is there evidence they are in some reasonably comprehensible serialization format?

Rummaging through the Keynote app runtime and class dumps with F-Script, the only evidence I've found is for some use of Protocol Buffers in the serialization classes which seem to be used for iWork, e.g.: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/iWorkImport.framework/TSPArchiverBase.h.

Quickly piping a few of the files through `protoc --decode_raw` with the first 0…16 bytes lopped off produced nothing obviously usable.

Comment: have you tried `file ThemeStylesheet.iwa` to see if file can figure out what they are?

Comment: Yes, and file just returns `data` (i.e., it has no idea).

Comment: I am also trying to decode this format, but focusing on Pages, so I'm looking at `Document.iwa`. Several people had suggested that Apple is using protocol buffers, so I wrote a script to `--decode_raw` all of the possible slices of the document (e.g. bytes 100 -> 3000). Like you, I found no usable output.

Comment: Try `strings /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages | grep google::protobuf` to grab all the protobuf data from the Pages app, which you may be able to relate to individual Pages docs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've done some work reverse engineering the format and published my results [here](https://github.com/obriensp/iWorkFileFormat). I've written up a [description](https://github.com/obriensp/iWorkFileFormat/blob/master/Docs/index.md) of the format and provided a sample project as well.

Basically, the .iwa files are Protobuf streams compressed using Snappy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting project, I like it!  Here is what I have found so far.

The first 4 bytes of each of the iwa files appear to be a length, with a tweak.  So it looks like there will not be any 'magic' to verify file type.

Look at Slide1.iwa:
First 4 bytes are `00 79 02 00`
File size is 637 bytes
take the first `00` off, and reverse the bytes: `00 02 79`
`00 02 79` == 633
637 - 633 = 4 bytes that hold the size of the file.

This checks out for the 4 files I looked at: Slide1.iwa, Slide2.iwa, Document.iwa, DocumentStylesheet.iwa

Comment: What you're seeing there is called "little endianness" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), not a "tweak" :)